# LReal Vs Real Data Types

Tags: plc

In PLC Structure Text what is main difference between a LReal Vs a Real data type? Which would you use when replacing a double or float when converting from a C based language to structure text with a PLC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LReal is a double precision real, float, or floating point variables that is a 64 bit signed value rather then a real is a single precision real, float, or floating point that is made from a 32 bit signed value. So it stores more in a LReal which makes LReal closer to a Double and a Float. The other thing to keep in mind is depending on the PLC it will convert a Real into a LReal for calculations. Plus a LReal is limited to 15 decimal places rather than a Real is 9 decimal places. So if you need more then 9 decimal places I would recommend LReal but if you need less I would stick with Real because with LReals you have to convert from a Integer to a Real to a LReal. So it would save you a step.